# Dynamic table from nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend

Trying to solve the issue with iteration of nested JSON,
    but it needs some advise.
    Cant properly generate  and  tags getting multiple values in one line.(subTable should be a new th tag. an example of result that i am trying to achieve
Thank you for advise

**FICO SCORE**

all        ≥ 760   0.50%   0.375%   0.25% 0%    -0.25% 
products    740     -759    0.375%   0.125% 0%   -0.375% -0.625%
            720     - 739   0.25%   -0.125%      -0.375% -0.625% -1.00%
            700     - 719   0.125%  -0.375%      -0.625% Not Eligible

Where they should be multiple.
    Please see my code below
    Thank you for any advise

```
    `var updated = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("tableJson"));


    function loop(obj, ul) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
            if(val && typeof val === "object") { // object, call recursively
                var ul2 = $("<td>").appendTo(
                    $("<tr>").appendTo(ul)
                );

                loop(val, ul2);
            } else {
                $("<td style='background-color: orange; color: white;;'>", {
                    id: key
                }).text(val).appendTo(ul);
            }
        });
    }


           var table = $("<table>");

           loop(updated, table);

        table.addClass("table").appendTo('#data');


            } else {
                $("<td style='background-color: orange; color: white;'>", {
                    id: key
                  }).text(val).appendTo(ul);
                }
            });
         }


           var table = $("<table>");

           loop(updated, table);

          table.addClass("table").appendTo('#data');

 `
              {
  "table": [
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "Fees"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Lender Fee",
            "$895"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Tax Service Fee",
            "$69"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Flood Certification Fee",
            "$12"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Texas Doc Prep Fee",
            "$150"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "Max of LTV/CLTV/HCLTV Ratio"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "≤ 60",
            "60.01-65",
            "65.01-70",
            "70.01-75",
            "75.01-80"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "FICO Score"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "≥ 760",
            "0.50%",
            "0.375%",
            "0.25%",
            "0%",
            "-0.25%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "740 - 759",
            "0.375%",
            "0.125%",
            "0%",
            "-0.375%",
            "-0.625%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "720 - 739",
            "0.25%",
            "-0.125%",
            "-0.375%",
            "-0.625%",
            "-1.00%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "700 - 719",
            "0.125%",
            "-0.375%",
            "-0.625%",
            "Not Eligible",
            "Not Eligible"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "Loan Amount"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "Up to $1M",
            "0.25%",
            "0.25%",
            "0.125%",
            "0%",
            "0%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            ">$1M Up to $1.5M",
            "0.25%",
            "0%",
            "-0.125%",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.375%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            ">$1.5M Up to $2M",
            "0.125%",
            "0%",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.375%",
            "Not Elig."
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            ">$2M Up to $2.5M",
            "0%",
            "-0.125%",
            "Not Eligible",
            "Not Eligible",
            "Not Eligible"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "Loan Purpose/Occupancy/Property Type"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "Purchase",
            "0.25%",
            "0.25%",
            "0.25%",
            "0.25%",
            "0.250%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "Cash-Out Refinance",
            "-0.250%",
            "-0.250%",
            "-0.250%",
            "Not Eligible",
            "Not Eligible"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "Second Home",
            "-0.125%",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.375%",
            "-0.75%",
            "Not Elig."
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "All Eligible Products",
            "2 Units",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.25%",
            "Not Eligible",
            "Not Eligible",
            "Not Eligible"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "Miscellaneous"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "BE DTI > 40%",
            "BE DTI > 40%",
            "-0.625%",
            "-0.625%",
            "-0.625%",
            "-0.625%",
            "-0.625%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Partial/No Impounds",
            "All States",
            "-0.15%",
            "-0.15%",
            "-0.15%",
            "-0.15%",
            "-0.15%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Subordinate Financing",
            "Subordinate Financing",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.25%",
            "-0.25%"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "Eligible Broker Incentives"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Tier",
            "Super Elite",
            "Elite",
            "Gold",
            "Silver",
            "Bronze"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Elite Bonus",
            "0.250%",
            "0.125%",
            "0%",
            "0%",
            "0%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Ethos Edge*",
            "0.125%",
            "0.125%",
            "0.125%",
            "0%",
            "0%"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Purchase Special (Purchase Primary Residence)",
            "0.125%",
            "0.125%",
            "0.125%",
            "0.125%",
            "0%"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subTable": [
        {
          "line": [
            "Max Price (Including All Adjustments)"

          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Loan Amount",
            "≤ $1M",
            ">$1M"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Fixed 30-Year",
            "102.00",
            "101.50"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "Fixed 15-Year",
            "101.50",
            "101.25"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "5/1 ARM",
            "100.85",
            "100.75"
          ]
        },
        {
          "line": [
            "7/1 ARM",
            "100.85",
            "100.75"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is. A [mcve] would help along with better problem description

Comment: Your code is not at all clear. You have a floating "else" without an "if", random places where you have closing brackets and parentheses... This misses the "verifiable" bit by a large margin.

Comment: Thank you all for checking,

Comment: Thank you all for checking, i am not that familiar with posting here.I will just explain the problem. The problem is that i cant really iterate the JSON i am getting. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sjcceyzu6x66cg/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-02-01%2023.09.30.png?dl=0)       And i am trying to get such a table out of this JSON